# Rmarkdown: use Komadown and Specify Pandoc Arguments

Tags: r-markdown, csl

Hi at all i have the following Problem:

I'm using Rmarkdown to write a Dokument. I'm also using the komadown package to use some bookdown features for referencing and be able to use the scrartcl document Class (Latex Output). I want to specify a citation style using a .csl file.

Normaly a simple csl: FILENAME.csl in the YAML header does the trick. But with the Komadown package this doesn't work.

My YAML Header is as follows, it finds my bibliography but it doesn't find the .csl file :(

```html
---
title: "Komadown Try"
bibliography: library.bib
csl: kaktus.csl
output: komadown::scrartcl
---
```

Furthermore i want to set the keep_tex option to TRUE or yes but this also doesn't work.

Many thanks in advance. Would be awesome if someone could help me out.

Answer (score 0):

i just got an answer to my questions. Maybe It'll help others that run into the same problem.

I can specify the csl file now. There was a bug in the code and the developer has fixed it. Currently the latest Version isn't on Cran so you have to download the developer Version from Github:

```
# install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("jolars/komadown")
```

If you have done that you can specify the csl and the keep_tex argument as follows:

```
---
title: "Thesis Template"
bibliography: library.bib
output: 
  komadown::scrartcl:
    keep_tex: yes
    csl: kaktus.csl
---
```